# Reading a string until press enter key or within array bounds

Tags: c

I want to read a string through keyboard to avoid buffer overflow. When i used 
`fgets(text,30,stdin)`, it reads but it also reads '\n' character. But i don't want to read '\n' character.

Comment: I don't understand how reading through a keyboard (as opposed to other data sources) avoids buffer overflow.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal:: It sounds like that or wrongly framed, i dont think `OP` meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char s[30];
scanf("%30[^\n]", s);
```

a little explain:

**%30[^\n]**

`30` which means read at most 30 chars, `[^\n]` which means read any char except '\n'.

Comment: should be `scanf("%29[^\n]", s)` ... and, unlike with `fgets`, the `'\n'` is left unread for the next input operation.

Comment: : Does not answer the question, `scanf` is susceptible to buffer overflow.

Comment: @Acme: %29[^\n] the number 29 tells scanf read at most 29 char into `s`

Comment: Oops,, completely missed that.. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

So remove the line feed once you have the string:

```
int get_line(char *buffer, size_t max)
{
  if(fgets(buffer, max, stdin) == buffer)
  {
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);
    if(len > 0 && buffer[len - 1] == '\0')
      buffer[--len] = '\0';
    return len;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Changed to return the length, which might save the caller some trouble. This means that for an empty string input, it will return 0.

Comment: Why don't you return the length? If you return it, the caller won't need to call `strlen` again.

Comment: @pmg: Sure, changed. It makes it impossible for the caller to know if the reading failed, or if the user just entered an empty string, though.

Answer (score 0):

Read with the `'\n'` character but remove it afterwards

```
if (fgets(text, 30, stdin)) {
  size_t tlen = strlen(text);
  if (len > 0) {
    if (text[tlen - 1] == '\n') {
      text[--tlen] = 0;
    } else {
      /* fgets read all it could
      ** but there wasn't a '\n'
      ** for the number of bytes available */
    }
  } else {
    /* empty string read: not even a '\n' */
  }
} else {
  /* fgets failed */
}
```